Will a plant eventually die if I keep it cut right back
There are a few plants / trees in my new garden that I don’t want. One for example is Cherry Laurel. I’ve cut them back to the stump but they keep sprouting new leaves. If I keep cutting them back, pulling off the leaves etc will they eventually die?  If not what are the best options to kill them? I don't really want to use chemicals on them.

Yes, at some point the plant will have exhausted their reserves and die.
But it’s going to be a tedious process and every time you let it grow a bit, it’s going to be a setback. And some will show a lot of stamina - thinking back to a similar battle I had with a hazel that grew intertwined with something that I didn’t want to disturb.
The safer option would be to not just cut down, but to dig out the roots as well, at minimum the larger ones. That should solve the issue for pretty much any tree or shrub and for the few that will try to regrow from root fragments, you can either dig more or keep up with the cut-and-strip you are using right now. Smaller plants are possibly also killable with a cover, blocking them from photosynthesis.

I rented an apartment with a blackberry bush growing out from the cracks in the sidewalk and completely overtaking a city bus stop.  I was only able to remove what was above the ground.  We dueled for three years.  The bush is still there.  Had fun though.

@MackM free blackberry jam every year, though?! Haha
